# cameras not found after rebooting

Tags: pi-4, camera, libcamera

I'm using raspberry pi 4 with [Arducam quad camera kit](https://www.arducam.com/product/arducam-16mp-imx519-autofocus-synchronized-quad-camera-kit-for-raspberry-pi-nvidia-jetson-nano-xavier-nx/) and [HD-Weitwinkel cameras](https://www.reichelt.de/de/de/raspberry-pi-kamera-5mp-160--rpi-wwcam-p148944.html?trstct=pos_1&nbc=1&&r=1). The cameras are not found when I reboot raspberrypi. However, when I reinstall raspberrypi os bullseye legacy, the cameras are recongized and it works as expected.

```
user@raspberrypi:~ $ libcamera-hello 
Made X/EGL preview window
[1:34:32.981645903] [1978]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:297 libcamera v0.0.0+4367-ad9428b4
ERROR: *** no cameras available ***
```

The os specifications are below:

```
user@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"


user@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -m
aarch64
```

The config file:

```
# For more options and information see
# http://rpf.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=1

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable infrared communication.
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=17
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=18

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

# Automatically load overlays for detected cameras
camera_auto_detect=0

# Automatically load overlays for detected DSI displays
display_auto_detect=1

# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

# Disable compensation for displays with overscan
disable_overscan=1

[cm4]
# Enable host mode on the 2711 built-in XHCI USB controller.
# This line should be removed if the legacy DWC2 controller is required
# (e.g. for USB device mode) or if USB support is not required.
otg_mode=1

[all]

[pi4]
# Run as fast as firmware / board allows
arm_boost=1

[all]
dtparam=i2_vc=on
dtparam=i2c10=on
dtoverlay=ov5647
dtoverlay=arducam-pivariety
```

I have reinstalled raspberry os bullseye legacy twice to confirm the issue. It recongnizes the cameras and works as expected, but when it's rebooted, non of the cameras are found.

Any suggestes regarding solving the issue is appreciated.